# How to save $_FILES to redis?

Tags: php, redis

I use redis to save PHP session information. I am wondering where are PHP's $_FILES variables saved? Is it possible to save these variables in redis? I want to do this to setup load balanced servers where users can upload files. Or may be I can use sticky sessions for this?

Comment: They are in the memory.

Comment: Furthermore the actual file is stored in the temporary location of $_FILES['xxx']['tmp_name'] that you need to move to the perm location (somewhere that all of your load balanced servers can reach to save the uploaded files).